# Translate a whole page without refreshing it

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, translation

The website I'm currently working on is written into two languages (fr/en). The method I'm using to translate the page is quite simple :

HTML

```
<ul id="switch">
    <li><a href="index.php?lang=en" title="English version">En</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.php?lang=fr" title="Version française">Fr</a></li>
</ul>
```

PHP (index.php)

```
<?php      
    // Translation
    if(isset($_GET['lang'])) {
        $lang = $_GET['lang'];
    }
    else {
        $lang = 'en';
    }

    switch($lang) {
        case 'en':
            $content = 'en.php';
            break;

        case 'fr':
            $content = 'fr.php';
            break;
    }

    include_once('lang/'.$content);
?>
```

Both `en.php` and `fr.php` contain an array filled with the actual content of the page in their respective language.

en.php (example)

```
<?php
    $version = array(
        'mainTitle' => 'Main title test',
        'noscript' => 'Noscript message test',
        'header' => 'Header test'
        // And so on, same thing for the french version
    );
?>
```

This system works fine and is sufficient for this website, but it implies a **page refresh** when the user switches from one language to another and that is precisely what I would like to **avoid**.

I guess I could work this out using a bit of AJAX (jQuery) but I am not exactly sure how to do this. Could you give me a few hint on how to implement this? I'm also open to suggestions on other possible ways of doing this - bearing in mind that it is a small scale project.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: answer partly depends on reason for no refresh. If there are user interactive changes in page at time of change, solution is more complex. If not, a simple ajax call can be made and reload new content

Comment: No, it's a very simple page really - no user interactive changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest the following, keep your language specific stuff in a Javascript dictionary, have a Javascript method to populate data from that dictionary, have a PHP server call which returns you contents for that dictionary (basically your language-specific content) and whenever user switches to a different language, make that PHP server call to populate your Javascript dictionary and call your Javascript method to populate.

Roughly, it would be something like this

```
function js_populate_content(lang)  {
    var content-data = $.get(lang); // Ajax call to your PHP service. You will need to do some parsing here (JSON would be easiest)
    // Populate your HTML elements using data
    document.getElementById('header').innerHTML = content-data['header'];
}
```

You could call this method at page load or you could still load it from php at first load

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var default_lang = 'en';
    js_populate_content(default_lang);
}
```

You should call this method whenever user changes language e.g.

```
$('a#language').on('click', function() {
    var new_lang = $('input#language').val();
    js_populate_content(new_lang);
}
```

Note: You should include jquery

Note2: See [jQuery get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) for proper syntax of $.GET

However, this is unnecessarily complex for just language switching. Similarly, you could load the entire page in AJAX and set your body to the newly loaded page based on language. Depends on whichever is easier for you to provide as a service call (providing only language dictionary vs. providing entire page in a specific language) For the latter, see [jQuery load](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: Or on a second thought, you could possibly load both of the languages in php and show/hide according to language. So you would have each item twice but one of them would always be hidden. (You could use class names for this and all you'd have to is to say $('.english').toggle();

Comment: Thanks for the useful insight, I'll look into it. I actually had the second option in mind but I don't exactly know how to achieve this properly.

Comment: `$.get` is lowercase, and can use `load()` to make it even simpler

Comment: Thanks Charlie, edited get to lowercase. And yep, you can see I present load as a second option.

Comment: Copied (with slight modifications) from the jQuery get page I mentioned, 

$.get('ajax/languages.php', function(data) {
  console.log(data); // This prints the server response to the console
  // Assuming your data is in JSON, you can then simply parse it e.g.
  var header = data.header;
});

Comment: Thanks! How do you actually display the data in page?

Comment: You should use Javascript for that, so you will find DOM elements using document.getElementById or simply using jQuery
Then set their innerHTML/value to values you get from your get() call 
Have a look at the js_populate_content function in my answer

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to refresh a page (making a new request to the PHP page), I'd suggest using a strings file in Javascript. This may require a bit of repetitive coding, but will work quite well.

Page.html:

```
<a href="#" onClick="setEnglish();">English</a> | <a href="#" onClick="setFrench();">Fran&ccedil;ais</a><br>

<span id="stringUsername"></span><br>
<input ...><br>
<span id="stringPassword"></span><br>
<input ...><br>
<span id="stringSex"></span>: <input ...><span id="stringMale"></span><input ...><span id="stringFemale"></span>

<script src="langEng.js"></script>
<script src="langFra.js"></script>
<script>
function setEnglish();
document.getElementById('stringUsername').innerHTML = $stringUsername;
document.getElementById('stringPassword').innerHTML = $stringPassword;
document.getElementById('stringSex').innerHTML = $stringSex;
document.getElementById('stringMale').innerHTML = $stringMale;
document.getElementById('stringFemale').innerHTML = $stringFemale;
</script>
```

langEng.js

```
$stringUsername='Username';
$stringPassword='Password';
$stringSex='Sex';
$stringMale='Male';
$stringFemale='Female';
```

langFra.js

```
$stringUsername='Username'; // Not sure about this translation.
$stringPassword='Mot de passe';
$stringSex='Sexe';
$stringMale='Homme';
$stringFemale='Femme';
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming everything on the page is translated, you might do something like this.

```
$('#switch a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // to stop the link from following the url
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $('body').load( href );
});
```

If there is a part of the `body`, say a `div` that contains all of translated bits, you could change it to

```
$('#translated_content_id').load( href );
```